# Great Genre / Theme combination in Game Studio Tycoon 3

Tags: game-studio-tycoon-3

I would like to know what are the other great combinations in Game Studio Tycoon 3. I already have done these types of game combinations, and listed are the effective ones:

- MOBA/RPG - ACTION/FIGHTING
- STEALTH - ACTION
- RACING - REALISTIC/ACTION

These are my combinations that works great but I would like to know the others.

Update:
Once you already made a combination like that, even if it is 10 years ago it still decrease the rating and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

These two are easily the best they work every time.

*RPG/SHOOTER - ACTION/ADVENTURE


RGP - FANTASY/ADVENTURE*

Answer (score 1):

Shoot/Moba war/sci fi is a good one

Comment: Thanks man! But I will still find more.

Answer (score 1):

Simulation/Shooter Scifi/Futuristic always gives me 8.+
Stealth/Shooter Action/War is a good one too[image]